# Creating variable that counts locations within buffer by monthly intervals using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, buffer, count, panel

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I have Sales locations and opening dates (and closing dates if applicable) for retailers in a state. I want to draw buffers and then count the number of other retail locations within a buffer for a given interval (preferably monthly intervals). My goal is to create one panel variable to use for assessments elsewhere (number of other retail locations in a particular business' buffer by month). I know how to draw the buffers, but not if there is a way to expand to the desired result.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You can use Summarize Within tool or Spatial Join tool to get the count of points in Polygon. Not sure what you are doing with a variable. That tools creates a new layer though. Sounds like you might not want that. but could join back up to original table to add counts each month.

Comment: So is there a way to use the summarize within tool, but only count the firms open in that month? It can either be by reading the opening date column, or with an indicator variable equal to one if it is open. It then sounds like I will have a ton of layers, which is not optimal but may be my only choice. My goal is to have a variable that I can use to control for the amount of firms open in an area to assess the effects of local policies.